# How do I call a function inside a function?

Tags: python, function, oop

```
import datetime

class User:

    def __init__(self, username, mail, date_of_birth, gender, password):
        self.username = username
        self.mail = mail
        self.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
        self.gender = gender
        self.password = password

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.mail

    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self.date_of_birth
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender

    def get_password(self):
        self.password

    def get_date(self):
        return self.date_of_birth

    log = ""


    def login2(self):

        global log
        log = input("input your username: ")
        if log == self.username:
            pwrd = input("whats your password?")
            if pwrd == self.password:
                print("Logged in!")


    @staticmethod
    def login_or_register():

        global log

        log = input("login or register: ")
        if log == "login" or "Login":
            login2()

Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999" ,"male", "Password987")
session1 = User.login_or_register()
```

So the login2() wont work for some reason.
Could someone help me out?

Comment: @MattDMo - No, `login2` only needs to exist by the time it is called... which happens at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @tdelaney it's hard to tell b/c the indentation isn't consistent, but I think OP is defining `login2()` *inside* of `login_or_register()`, so when the outer function is run, the call to `login2()` occurs before it's actually defined.

Comment: still the same error.... NameError: name 'login2' is not defined

Comment: Can you post a running example? We need a class definition and the indentation to be correct. Since `login_or_register` is a static method, it has no visibility to the `login2` instance method. Do you want `login_or_register` to return an instance of the `User` class?

Comment: @loky you can't call a instance method from a static method

Comment: Alright! How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your intent, but you could make this a class method that creates an instance of its class.

```
@classmethod
def login_or_register(cls):
    log = input("login or register: ")
    if log == "login" or "Login":
        user = cls()
        user.login2()
        return user
```

But from the way you use it

```
Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999" ,"male", "Password987")
session1 = User.login_or_register()
```

I think it should just be a regular method

```
def login_or_register(self):
    log = input("login or register: ")
    if log == "login" or "Login":
        self.login2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an instance method from a class method. Login2 can be an instance method as well. Then instead of calling it statically, call it on the Matt instance as follows.

```
import datetime

class User:

    def __init__(self, username, mail, date_of_birth, gender, password):
        self.username = username
        self.mail = mail
        self.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
        self.gender = gender
        self.password = password

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.mail

    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self.date_of_birth
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender

    def get_password(self):
        self.password

    def get_date(self):
        return self.date_of_birth

    log = ""


    def login2(self):

        global log
        log = input("input your username: ")
        if log == self.username:
            pwrd = input("whats your password?")
            if pwrd == self.password:
                print("Logged in!")

    def login_or_register(self):

        global log

        log = input("login or register: ")
        if log == "login" or "Login":
            self.login2()

Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999" ,"male", "Password987")
session1 = Matt.login_or_register()
```